# Embed Ruby in C and exntend

Tags: c++, c, ruby, embed

I have a requirement where I need to embed Ruby code in C++ (I could achieve this) and extend some functionality. When I try to call (require) my extension module, the program fails.

I have pasted a jist of the code below:

### main.cpp

```
#include <ruby.h>

static VALUE Sum(VALUE rb_self, VALUE rb_param1, VALUE rb_param2)
{
    double val1 = NUM2DBL(rb_param1);
    double val2 = NUM2DBL(rb_param2);
    return rb_float_new(val1+val2);
}

void Init_myMod()
{
    myMod = rb_define_module("myMod");
    rb_define_module_function(myMod, "Sum", Sum, 2);
}

int main()
{
 ... Init ruby method...

    rb_require("myRubyfile");
    Init_myMod(); // This is where I need to push my ruby extension.
    rb_funcall(rb_mKernel, rb_intern("helloworld"), 0 , NULL);
.... 
}
```

### myRubyfile.rb

```
require "myMod"

def helloworld()
    puts "Hello world"
    #puts "Sum of.. " + myMod.sum(4, 5)
end
```

The problem is if I dont use require "myMod" the code works and prints "Hello World", but if I use require.., the code dumps.

This is my requirement where I need to embed the ruby script in C, and reuse some of the C methods in ruby (extension).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? When you say embed I assume you mean run a ruby script? Are you using windows or Linux? If you are just trying to run the script and you are using Linux there is a simple way to do putting this in a bash script.

Comment: Hello @cokedude I am running this on windows. I get the below error:
<main>: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0013fc TOP    [FINISH]


Thanks for helping.

Comment: It would really help if you provided a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a segfault because the Ruby VM segfaults when there is an uncaught exception. You need to use something like `rb_rescue` or `rb_protect` to wrap the code which could raise an exception.

`require "myMod"` is raising an exception because `require` is only used to load files. You don't need to require anything because you're creating the module directly in the VM's memory. So... why the error? Well, if you were to write your module in Ruby, you'd get a syntax error:

```
module myMod
  ...
end
# SyntaxError: class/module name must be CONSTANT
```

But when you use `rb_define_module`, rather than raise an exception, Ruby does a tricky thing: it creates the module *but doesn't expose it to the Ruby code*. In order to expose the module to Ruby, just make the name valid:

```
// .cpp
rb_define_module("MyMod");
```

and

```
# .rb
puts "Sum of.. " + MyMod.Sum(4, 5).to_s
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. :). Your suggested code is working for me.

Comment: can you also share an example using rb_rescue or rb_protect to catch any exception in the able code please?

Comment: Here's a good blog post on the topic: http://clalance.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-5.html

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work. Make a bat script to your ruby script file and change system to the appropriate system call. Not sure if system() works in Windows. I have run many bash scripts this way so I would assume you can do the same thing in Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Starting now:");
    system("/path_to_script/script_name");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you miss understood. I am able to execute the ruby script and it works fine. I need to extend the library (from C code) which I can use in ruby using require "..". IF you can use my example and modify it for me, it will be helpful.